# I want to deploy my Node.js Server on Azure App Services

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, server, azure-appservice

I have been trying to deploy my node.js server on azure using app service but everytime there is this new error, Sometimes the build command is not available in configuration, sometimes it cannot fetch the content.
I am sick of doing this, anyone please provide me a proper documentation to deploy my server, I couldn't find any documentation which is accurate and up to date with their latest versions.
Please help me find the best documentation you know.

I tried app services, I directly configure the app with what they asked and deployed by CI/CD with help of github, I set the env variables too. I did everything they asked for!

Comment: What is the Node version you are using ?

Comment: Have you considered putting it in docker and deployed as docker container instead?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**I have created NodeJs application and deployed to Azure using GitHub actions:**

[image]

**Steps to deploy:**

- Create App Service in Azure Portal.
- Make sure you have the below settings in *web app=>Settings=>Configuration=>Application Settings:*

```
WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=Node_version>
WEBSITES_PORT=<Port_number_of_your_application>
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true
```

[image]

- Open your web app =>Deployment =>Deployment Center=> Select *GitHub* as *Source* and signin with your GitHub account fill the other fields accordingly with your repository details:

[image]

- Once you save the details, it will generate yml file(workflow to deploy) in github and start the deployment process.
- You can track the deployment status in Actions in GitHub or Logs in Deployment Center of App Service.

**My workflow:**

```
name: Building and deploying Node.js app to Azure Web App - <web_app_name>

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
      
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: .

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: '<your_web_app_name>'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_XXXXXXXXXX }}
          package: .
```

**Deployed Successfully:**

**GitHub:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Alternatives:**

As an alternative, you can consider deploying NodeJs application through [VSCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=linux&pivots=development-environment-vscode#deploy-to-azure) and [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=linux&pivots=development-environment-cli#deploy-to-azure).